# How does sapply() apply a function with undefined (with no default) parameters

Tags: r, rest, sapply

The following code block taken from [chernan's sample REST queries](https://github.com/chernan/RESTfulAccessExamples/blob/master/bioDBnet.Rmd) will apply FUN to a list of parameters, but "param_name" is not provided.  How is this possible?

```
rcurl_request <- function(service_url, parameters) {

# Collapse all parameters into one string
all_parameters <- paste(
    sapply(names(parameters), 
           FUN=function(param_name, parameters) {
               paste(param_name, paste(parameters[[param_name]], collapse=','), collapse='', sep='=')
           }, 
           parameters),
    collapse="&")

# Paste base URL and parameters
requested_url <- paste0(service_url, all_parameters)

# Encode URL (in case there would be any space character for instance)
requested_url <- URLencode(requested_url)

# Start request to service
response <- getURL(requested_url, .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))

return(response)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*apply` family of functions are designed to apply `FUN` to the elements of the object supplied to the respective `*apply` function.

In your example, the elements to which `FUN` is applied are the *individual* elements of `names(parameters)`. `sapply()` takes the first element, `names(parameters)[1]` and passes that to `FUN` as the first argument. Hence `param_name` is used to refer to `names(parameters)[1]`, then to `names(parameters)[2]`, and so on.

In other words, `sapply()` arranges to pass, in turn, the elements of `sapply()`s first argument to `FUN` supplying these elements as the first argument of `FUN`.

You can see this more clearly with this simpler example:

```
sapply(1:10, FUN = function(i) {writeLines(paste("working on", i)); i})
```

hence `i` takes on the values 1, 2, ..., 10, in turn and the anonymous function works on each of them:

```
> sapply(1:10, FUN = function(i) {writeLines(paste("working on", i)); i})
working on 1
working on 2
working on 3
working on 4
working on 5
working on 6
working on 7
working on 8
working on 9
working on 10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`names(parameters)` is being passed to `param_name`. A more basic example: `sapply(df1, mean)`. The implication being `sapply(df1, function(x) mean(x))`. In this case each element of df1 is being passed to `mean` as the argument `x`. The apply functions take the first argument and pass it to the specified function (the second argument of an apply function)

For example:

```
sapply(mtcars, mean)

       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750 
        vs         am       gear       carb 
  0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

Also, the `sapply()` is constructed as `sapply(x, FUN,...)` the `...` is any additional arguments passed to the function `FUN`. In your example, `parameters`is being passed as the second argument (`names(parameters)` is implicitly the first).